# Need help on using Google Maps in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google maps API on my VUE JS based project and I am getting below-mentioned errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

This is the codebase that I am using.

[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: You can use vue2-google-maps. Its a small library that helps with google maps in vue.

Comment: Are you able to share your full code in a sandbox/playground like this [Vue Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue?from-embed)? This will help others replicate your issue.